# xslt: Using substring-before with axes

Tags: xslt

I have the following Xml file (as an example, not the real one):

```
<TestCases>
   <TestCase>
      <Name>TC1</Name>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstA=Value1</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstB=Value2</Line>
            <Line>InstC=Value1</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstA=Value3</Line>
            <Line>InstC=Value1</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstD=Value2</Line>
            <Line>InstB=Value1</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstA=Value4</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstC=Value5</Line>
            <Line>InstE=Value6</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
   </TestCase>
   <TestCase>
      <Name>TC2</Name>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstC=Value8</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstD=Value7</Line>
            <Line>InstB=Value3</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstC=Value5</Line>
            <Line>InstA=Value6</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstD=Value2</Line>
            <Line>InstB=Value1</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstA=Value4</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Code>
            <Line>InstA=Value5</Line>
            <Line>InstB=Value6</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
   </TestCase>
</TestCases>
```

What I want is apply a template for each unique InstX string (ignoring what comes after '='. I have been using:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="TestCases/TestCase/TestCaseElement[Code]/Code/Line[not(substring-before(.,'==')=substring-before(preceding::Code/Line,'=='))]"/>
```

But this doesn't work.

Finally as output I want something like:

```
<Values>
  <Value>InstA</Value>
  <Value>InstB</Value>
  <Value>InstC</Value>
  <Value>InstD</Value>
  <Value>InstE</Value>
<Values>
```

Important is I cannot use any extension function. Just plain Xslt 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, you don't need extension functions here.

You could use `xsl:for-each-group`...

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="TestCases/TestCase/TestCaseElement[Code]/Code/Line" group-by="substring-before(.,'=')">
  <Value>
    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
  </Value>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Or you could use the `distinct-values` function...

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(TestCases/TestCase/TestCaseElement[Code]/Code/Line/substring-before(.,'='))">
  <Value>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </Value>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed the answer.